# Strange geom_vline() behavior in ggplot when using coord_trans() with custom transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2, scaletransform

I am trying to use a [log-modulus transformation](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2014/07/14/log-transformation-of-pos-neg.html) in my plot. It was working fine...

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

log_modulus_trans <- function() 
  trans_new(name = "log_modulus", 
            transform = function(x) sign(x) * log(abs(x) + 1), 
            inverse = function(x) sign(x) * ( exp(abs(x)) - 1 ))

# fake data
set.seed(1)
d <- data_frame(
  tt = rep(1:10, 3),
  cc = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 10),
  xx = c(rnorm(10, mean = 100, sd = 10), 
         rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 10),
         rnorm(10, mean = -100, sd = 10)))

ggplot(data = d, 
       mapping = aes(x = tt, y = xx, group = cc)) +
  geom_line() + 
  coord_trans(y = "log_modulus")
```

[image]

When I tried to add a `geom_vline()` things got weird...

```
ggplot(data = d, 
       mapping = aes(x = tt, y = xx, group = cc)) +
  geom_line() + 
  coord_trans(y = "log_modulus") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 5)
```

[image]

Any idea how to get `geom_vline()` to go from the top to the bottom of the plot window... or a work around hack?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `geom_segment`

```
ggplot(data = d, 
       mapping = aes(x = tt, y = xx, group = cc)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_segment(x = 5, xend = 5, y = -150, yend = 150) +
  coord_trans(y = "log_modulus")
```

[image]